# Simon Says in Python

Tags: python

Simon Says" in python is a memory game where "Simon" outputs a sequence of 10 characters (R, G, B, Y) and the user must repeat the sequence. Create a for loop that compares the two strings. For each match, add one point to user_score. Upon a mismatch, end the game. Ex: The following patterns yield a user_score of 4: simonPattern: R, R, G, B, R, Y, Y, B, G, Y
userPattern:  R, R, G, B, B, R, Y, B, G, Y
I am given this part of the code but I am clueless because I am a math major stuck in another mans world!!

```
user_score = 0
simon_pattern = 'RRGBRYYBGY'
user_pattern  = 'RRGBBRYBGY'

'''Your solution goes here'''

print('User score:', user_score)
```

Comment: Sounds like you just don't know anything about python. That's not a bad thing, we all start somewhere.
I'd recommend making a function that takes in a list, and prints the elements of the list. That would be a good start.
Then, make a function that takes in two lists, L1 and L2, and prints L1[1], L2[1], L1[2], L2[2]...

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. Please ask with a specific question instead of asking for free code solutions

Comment: Let me give you some clues: first you'll need to [find the size](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) of both the correct and the user pattern. [If](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm) they are different, you can tell the answer is wrong. Otherwise you'll have to [loop](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loops.htm) over each position of the string (you can use `simon_pattern[i]`, where `i` is an `int` between 0 and "the length of the string - 1") and compare them. The first one to be different tells you the answer is wrong.

Comment: Programming and math share a lot of the same underlying logic and problem-solving skills. General advice: Start by developing a firm understanding of the problem, temporarily ignoring the code. Once you have that, develop an understanding of basic programming concepts such as loops, conditionals and variables. If you have a specific question about these concepts, googling it should give you your answer. As mentioned above, SO is not a code-writing service. Good luck!

Comment: Wasn't asking for free code... was asking for direction

Comment: Didn't your instructor give you some kind of direction before giving you this assignment?

Answer (score 2):

Program logic would be,

1. Have a for loop which would run for the length of the simon_says variable
2. check if user_pattern character == simon_says character (chop each character and substring them to do this)
3. if the condition is satisfied increment user_score by 4
4. else break out of the loop

This algorithm would work provided that the simon_says and user_pattern variables both are of same length. IF not i'd suggest find the length of the two variables and run the loop for the shortest string instead of simon_says.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is the direction I was looking for!